# Back-up software for Windows

Tags: windows, backup

Can anyone recommend any open-source back-up software for Windows, especially one which can incrementally and automatically update very large files, including ideally the whole system, or at least any specified folders?

I have a Synology NAS, but its software chokes with large files (such as my Thunderbird email files), and I was told by their support that I would need a back-up program to manually update large files.

Comment: Does it need to be open source? There are very good free options that arn't Foss. Do you want file or volume level backups? Which is the minimum version of windows you need to target?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply---esp. volume-level, but also file. Minimum would be Windows 10. And no, it doesn't need to be open source or even free, but I was hoping that something as fundamental as back-up would already be in open source form. I'm currently trying out Acronis which looks promising in its functionality, but it is paid.

Answer (score 3):

I really like Bvckup2.  Like their website says... it's simple, fast backup with polish and a focus on doing one thing well.  Just reviewing their website will give you a good sense of the nice clean interface with plenty of features.  I think the price is fair for what you get.

https://www.bvckup2.com/

Comment: I use this too! Different roles tho. bvckup is lovely for *file level* backups. I use it to sync specific folders. I use veem endpoint for system backups (which get replicated with bvckup)

Comment: A great tool for file sync is "Beyond Compare".  You get file sync, but you also have visual control to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I've had reasonable luck with [veem endpoint backup](http://www.veeam.com/endpoint-backup-free.html). You'll need to install a more recent version for windows 10 support. As far as I can tell, you can only really run one backup job per system, but with that...

- incremental backups are supported
- Runs live, on a schedule, using volume snapshots.
- merges backups on schedule - by default it keeps 7 days of backups and merges the oldest one in
- Lets you do one off backups for when you're about to do something you suspect *might* be stupid, and are smart enough to know you want to roll back time
- Lets you mount a backup to restore individual files. And since its incremental, you can pick which backup to restore it from
- Has the option of backing up the entire system, specific volumes or specific files
- Will restore to a smaller drive and let you resize when restoring (which was very useful when I decided to use it to migrate to an SSD from a larger spinning rust drive).

Its Gratis, but not Libre, for both personal and commercial use. I do believe you need to register an account with them to download it.

Answer (score 1):

Cobian Backup is a free data backup software. It can help you and automate the tedious chore backups.

The software, once installed, provides a wizard to easily set up your data backups, this form of tasks. Then there is selected for each of them:

the type of archiving: are supported incremental backup, differential, complete;
directories, files to copy destination and the location where the backup is made. It should be noted that this can be a network or an FTP server location;
the type of compression (ZIP, SQX), encrypted (RSA, Blowfish, DES, ...) or not;
the frequency of the task execution (weekly, monthly, time ...)
archiving exceptions (type of file, directory, or entire files);
external programs that can be started / stopped the beginning or end backup;
Finally you can even choose a login / pwd extra with which to launch the backup (including access to a network resource).
http://www.cobiansoft.com/index.htm